# Submitting Django CreateView form to itself

Tags: python, django

As a newcomer to Django, I'm struggling to achieve my ultimate aim of submitting a form to the same page on which it's defined and displaying values entered in the form within text elements of an SVG diagram, displayed below the form.

Thus far, I've managed to create a form using a `CreateView` and can submit the contents of that form to a separate view which displays the entered values in SVG format...

**models.py**

```
class Diagram(models.Model):
    val1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    val2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('diagram-results', kwargs={'diagram_id': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```
class DiagramForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Diagram
        fields = ['val1', 'val2']
```

**views.py**

```
def show(request, diagram_id):
    try:
        diagram = Diagram.objects.get(pk=diagram_id)
    except Diagram.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Diagram does not exist")
    return render(request, 'calc_app/diagram.svg', {'diagram': diagram})  

class DiagramCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Diagram
    form_class = DiagramForm
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('diagram/add/', DiagramCreateView.as_view(), name='diagram-add'),
    path('diagram/<int:diagram_id>/', views.show, name='diagram-results'),
]
```

**diagram_form.html**

```
{% extends "calc_app/base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}   
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**diagram.svg**

```
<svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text id="val1" stroke="#ddd" y="50.0" x="50.0">{{ diagram.val1 }}</text>
  <text id="val2" stroke="#ddd" y="50.0" x="50.0">{{ diagram.val2 }}</text>
</svg>
```

I'd like to take this one step further and submit the entered form values back to the same page (rather than a separate page/view) and show the results within the SVG diagram. It's straightforward enough to combine the HTML form and SVG diagram into a single template by including the following line immediately below the closing form tag in the **diagram_form.html** template...

```
{% include "calc_app/diagram.svg" %}
```

What I'm struggling to do is post the form contents back to the page it originated from. Can anyone shed any light on how best to do this using the aforementioned building blocks (or more appropriate ones)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: At present , after submitting the form , which page is shown to the user/ where is the user redirected to?

Comment: After submitting the DiagramCreateView form, the inner workings direct the user to the URL named in the get_absolute_url method of the Diagram model i.e. the URL named 'diagram-results' (which refers to 'diagram/<int:diagram_id>/').

Comment: and instead , you want the user to be directed back to the form, with SVG displayed , right?

Comment: Correct. After form submission, I want to display the SVG (populated with values from the submitted form) immediately below the form, so that if the user wants to enter different values they simply need to scroll up and resubmit the form.

Comment: I have written the code in the answer, could you try that and check if it servers your purpose.

Comment: I'll let you know once I've had an opportunity to try your suggested code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modify create view by overriding post method, as following lines of code,

```
class DiagramCreateView(CreateView):
model = Diagram
form_class = DiagramForm

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().post(request,*args,**kwargs)
    form = DiagramForm(request.POST)
    return render(request,'calc_app/diagram_form.html',{'form':form,'diagram':self.object})
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, update your ***`diagram_form.html`*** file as below, to handle the `svg` image

```html
{% extends "calc_app/base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

<div>
    {% include "calc_app/diagram.svg" %}
</div>
```

Note that, I have used the [***`include`***--[Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag of Django here to re-use the `diagram.svg`

Then, update the ***`DiagramCreateView`*** class by overriding the **`form_valid(...)`** and **`get_context_data(...)`** method and also updating the value of **`template_name`** attribute

```
class DiagramCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Diagram
    form_class = DiagramForm
    template_name = "sample/diagram_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return render(
            request=self.request,
            template_name=self.template_name,
            context=self.get_context_data()
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx["diagram"] = self.object
        return ctx
```

In the end, this would result in a below setup,
[image: EndResult]

Comment: Are there any advantages to your approach over the more concise earlier answer?

Comment: I don't see any *"advantages"*. But, I won't choose that answer if I have a choice because the `super()` method internally calls some of the methods (ex: `form_valid(...)`) and which doesn't make any effect. Some people may think *"the `super()` call doesn't make any difference in the result and can obtain the result in a neat way"*, but, some people may think *"why should I execute irrelevant methods, that may take an extra `ms` while execution"*. I belong to the second category :)

Comment: I believe in following Python principle which states "simple is better than complex" even if it take a mili second extra and 4 lines of code to execute instead of 11 lines of code and a mili second less.

Comment: Additionally , if milliseconds are important, then code should be written in C++ which is much faster than Python.

Comment: Just to point out, count 11  is not correct (did I forgot to count? :o) and these extra methods are not something that gets executed ***extra***. I admit that we have to use languages like c++, rust, etc to get top-notch precision over time.